# How can I get a sequence of two array items in an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

i am looking for a way to get a sequence of two array items in an array, especially an array of length 4

for example,

```js
[[1,0], [2,3], [5,4], [0,0], [3,2], [1,4], [0,5]]
```

... should return :

```js
[[3,2], [2,3], [1,4], [0,5]]
```

3 --^ 2 -----^ 1 ----^ 0 -----^ so `[3, 2, 1, 0]` for x

```js
[[3,2], [2,3], [1,4], [0,5]]
```

2 -----^ 3 -----^ 4 ----^ 5 -----^ so `[2, 3, 4, 5]` for y

```js
[[x1, y1], [x2, y2], [x3, y3], [x4, y3]]
// +1 or -1 for the first index
// and +1 or -1 for the second index
[[3,2], [2,3], [1,4], [0,5]] // is a sequence
[[0,0], [1,1], [2,2], [3,3]] // is a sequence
[[4,4], [3,3], [2,2], [1,1]] // is a sequence
[[4,3], [3,3], [2,2], [1,1]] // is not a sequence
[[1,2], [2,3], [4,5], [5,6]] // is a sequence
```

i tried to use for loops but it's illegible and confusing, maybe too difficult
and this but it's only counting the longest sequence, not returning it :

```js
const Z = x.sort((a, b) => a - b).reduce((count, val, i) => {
  return count += val + 1 === x[i + 1] ? 1 : 0
}, 1);
const Z2 = y.sort((a, b) => a - b).reduce((count, val, i) => {
  return count += val + 1 === y[i + 1] ? 1 : 0
}, 1);
      
console.log(Z, Z2) // 4 4
```

Comment: The criteria for returning `[[3,2], [2,3], [1,4], [0,5]]` is unclear to me. The problem itself is probably simple, but you may want to further explain why such output is provided, unless it's just me not understanding the algorithm.

Comment: @briosheje it looks like the two items add to 5.

Comment: okay sorry, let's try to help you : [[x+3, y+3], [x+2, y+2], [x+1, y+1], [x, y]] for example

Comment: @briosheje or maybe it's to do with the first number?

Comment: I still don't understand what the algorithm is supposed to do, who defines x and y? Are you asking for all values of x/y that meet this criteria?

Comment: is `2, 3, 4, 6` valid sequence or it should not skip?

Comment: @briosheje it can be [[0,0], [1,1], [2,2], [3,3]], just a sequence for x and y

Comment: @cute_programmer sequence is 0, 1, 2, 3 or 4, 3, 2, 1

Comment: @JuanMendes i am doing a connect 4 and all of these are coordinates of cells.
a player has an attribute placedCells with an array of his moves, a diagonal win need a sequence for x and y

Comment: @NinaScholz [0,0] is not in a 4 length sequence

Comment: @Preur Don't you think you should have started your question with the fact that you're trying to implement connect 4? I would rewrite the question explaining that and how x/y maps to the game. It's unclear what you are trying to do.

Comment: @JuanMendes because I want to do everything myself, just that here i am stuck for a sorting and filtering algorithm, i just wanted to know how to retrieve a sequence, for example in the connect 4, a sequence of 4

Comment: @Preur Don't answer questions about your post in comments. Improve your post so anyone can understand it from reading the post alone. You will still solve the overall problem yourself, but your current algorithm description has a lot of holes in it. Explaining that the first array is a list of moves and what x/y means is the beginning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add the points to an object and check the order of four by using a factor of adding an offset for `x` and `y`.

If needed, you could add the check for horizontal or vertical points, too.

```js
const
    four = array => {
        const
            data = array.reduce((r, [x, y]) => ((r[x] ??= {})[y] = true, r), {}),
            check = ([x, y], i, j) => {
                const temp = [];
                for (let k = 0; k < 4; k++, x += i, y += j) {
                    if (data[x]?.[y]) temp.push([x, y]);
                    else break;
                }
                if (temp.length === 4) return temp;
            };
            
        let result;
        array.some(p => result = check(p, 1, 1) || check(p, -1, 1));
        return result;
    },
    data = [[1, 0], [2, 3], [5, 4], [0, 0], [3, 2], [1, 4], [0, 5]];

console.log(four(data)); // [[3, 2], [2, 3], [1, 4], [0, 5]]
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: thank you so much, worked perfectly, now i have to see how you did that!